# How to join multi time one tible to other

Tags: mysql, sql, join

have 2 tables in database for books
one with genres

```
--------------------
| id | genre       |
--------------------
| 1  |   genre 1   |
| 2  |   genre 2   |
| 3  |   genre 3   |
| 4  |   genre 2   |
--------------------
```

and table books with 4 columns for category for each books

```
---------------------------------
| id | name | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
---------------------------------
|7427| book1| 3  | 1  | 0  | 0  |
```

how i can get all categories for book by ID?

i try someone like this for 2 genres but result for second category is same like fist

```
SELECT 
    books.id as bid,
    c1, 
    genre.name as g1_name,
    c2,
    genre.name as g2_name
FROM books 
    Left join genre on books.c1 = genre.id 
where books.id="7427"
;
```

Comment: I can't get what are you asking. Can you explain more what you want? Also from which table `id_gerne` and `id_gerne_1` come? Also show your expected output.

Comment: i want to recive in result some like this


| 7427 | book1 | 3 |genre 3 | 1 | genre 1 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Please add your expected output in your question.

Comment: | 7427 | book1 | 3 |genre 3 | 1 | genre 1 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: 1. Normalise your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in your case it's probably a lot more straight forward to just run sub queries:

```
SELECT 
    books.id as bid,
    c1,
    (SELECT name FROM genre WHERE id = c1) as c1_genre,
    c2,
    (SELECT name FROM genre WHERE id = c2) as c2_genre,
    c3,
    (SELECT name FROM genre WHERE id = c3) as c3_genre,
    c4,
    (SELECT name FROM genre WHERE id = c4) as c4_genre
FROM books 
where books.id="7427";
```

Further, add an index to the table `genre` that's made up of `id, name` so that it never has to read the data page for these queries.

Comment: Thanks guys!
thats is helpfull!

Comment: @NikolayKolev, if so, please say thanks by simply up voting and accepting an answer. I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: i will do, simple first find how to do :)
im newbie.

Comment: hmmm 'Vote Up requires 15 reputation'

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
select b.id,
       b.name,
       b.c1,
       g1.genre genre1,
       b.c2,
       g2.genre genre2,
       b.c3,
       g3.genre genre3,
       b.c4,
       g4.genre genre4
from books b
left join genre g1 on b.c1 = g1.id 
left join genre g2 on b.c2 = g2.id 
left join genre g3 on b.c3 = g3.id 
left join genre g4 on b.c4 = g4.id 
where b.id='7427'
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98e0dc/2).

Alternatively:

```
select b.id,
       b.name,
       b.c1,
       max(case g.id when c1 then g.genre end) genre1,
       b.c2,
       max(case g.id when c2 then g.genre end) genre2,
       b.c3,
       max(case g.id when c3 then g.genre end) genre3,
       b.c4,
       max(case g.id when c4 then g.genre end) genre4
from books b
left join genre g on g.id in (b.c1, b.c2, b.c3, b.c4)
where b.id='7427'
group by b.id
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98e0dc/5).